# Not able to parse date in UAT environment however works in my local

Tags: c#, asp.net

string abc = "8:30 AM";

var dateAbc = DateTime.Parse(abc,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;

This works fine in my local, however throwing this error in UAT

System.FormatException

Message: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source: mscorlib

at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)

Any insights or suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime.ParseExact, the format of your string representation must match the specified format exactly.

- if you use "hh" for hours, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
- if you use "HH" for hours, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
- if you add "tt" The Am/Pm designator.

With that in mind, Here is something I've quickly mocked up...

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact( "08:30 AM","hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ).TimeOfDay;
```